# Generic constructor from integer input for a Rational Number object

Tags: generics, rust, casting, traits

I am implementing a rational number library for personal use, and would like a construction option to be from_integer, where the method takes any data type capable of being cast as an i32. I tried the following

```rust
pub fn from_integer<T: Into<i32>>(input: T) -> Result<Self, String> {
    Ok(Rational{
        numerator: input as i32,
        denominator: 1
    })
}
```

but get this error

```
non-primitive cast: `T` as `i32`

an `as` expression can only be used to convert between primitive types or to coerce to a specific trait objectrustc(E0605)
lib.rs(97, 24): an `as` expression can only be used to convert between primitive types or to coerce to a specific trait object
```

Have I got the wrong trait, or is there a different way I should express that I want the input cast this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`as`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/operator-expr.html#type-cast-expressions) is always useless with generics.

You're already correct in having a [`Into<i32>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.Into.html) bound on `T`, but you're not actually using the trait: Replace `input as i32` with [`input.into()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.Into.html#tymethod.into).

```rust
pub fn from_integer<T: Into<i32>>(input: T) -> Result<Self, String> {
    Ok(Rational{
        numerator: input.into(),
        denominator: 1
    })
}
```